# Trying to compute my own Histogram without opencv calcHist()

Tags: c++, function, opencv, image-processing, histogram

What I'm trying to do is writing a function that calculates a Histogram of a greyscale image with a forwarded Number of Bins (anzBin) which the histograms range is divided in. Then I'm running through the Image Pixels compairing their value to the different Bins and in case a value fits, increasing the value of the Bin by 1

```
   vector<int> calcuHisto(const IplImage *src_pic, int anzBin) 
   {
   CvSize size = cvGetSize(src_pic);
   int binSize = (size.width / 256)*anzBin;
   vector<int> histogram(anzBin,0);

    for (int y = 0; y<size.height; y++) 
    {
         const uchar *src_pic_point =
        (uchar *)(src_pic->imageData + y*src_pic->widthStep);
       for (int x = 0; x<size.width; x++) 
       {
        for (int z = 0; z < anzBin; z++)
        {
            if (src_pic_point[x] <= z*binSize)
            {
                histogram[src_pic_point[x]]++;
            }

        }

    }
}
return histogram;
}
```

But unfortunately it's not working...
What is wrong here?
Please help

Comment: `int binSize = (size.width / 256)*anzBin;` Is `binSize` 0 here because of integer math? I mean if size.width is less than 256 wouldn't `binSize` be 0?

Comment: It is not that what I'm trying to compute, you're right. My target is something like: binSize = (Image()/256)*anzBin but how can I do that?

Comment: Replace 256 with 256.0

Comment: Oh I hate myself... that would solve the binSize Problem but I still have a Problem with the Vector histogram

Comment: can you give a small example and desired result?

Comment: Sure: So I open a greyscale Image and want to summarize the grey values of this picture into bins. Lets say I want my Histogram array to have ten bins. A 8Bit greyscale Image has 255 different shades of gray so it would be somthing like: In bin 1 I insert all grey values between 0 - 25.5 in bin 2 values from 25.6 - 50 get insertet and so on...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few issues I can see

1. Your binSize calculation is wrong
2. Your binning algorithm is one sided, and should be two sided
3. You aren't incrementing the proper bin when you find a match

**1. binsize calculation**

`bin size =  your range / number of bins`

**2. two sided binning**

```
if (src_pic_point[x] <= z*binSize)
```

you need a two sided range of values, not a one sided inequality. Imagine you have 4 bins and values from 0 to 255. Your bins  should have the following ranges

```
bin     low     high
0       0       63.75
1       63.75   127.5
2       127.5   191.25
3       191.25  255
```

For example: a value of `57` should go in bin 0. Your code says the value goes in all the bins! Because its always `<= z*binsize` You need something something with a lower and upper bound.

**3. Incrementing the appropriate bin**

You are using `z` to loop over each bin, so when you find a match you should increment bin `z`, you don't use the actual pixel value except when determining which bin it belongs to

this would likely be buffer overrun imagine again you have 4 bins, and the current pixel has a value of 57. This code says increment bin 57. But you only have 4 bins (0-3)

```
histogram[src_pic_point[x]]++;
```

you want to increment only the bin the pixel value falls into

```
histogram[z]++;
```

**CODE**
With that in mind here is revised code (it is untested, but should work)

```
vector<int> calcuHisto(const IplImage *src_pic, int anzBin) 
{
    CvSize size = cvGetSize(src_pic);
    double binSize = 256.0 / anzBin;        //new definition
    vector<int> histogram(anzBin,0);        //i don't know if this works so I
                                            //so I will leave it

    //goes through all rows
    for (int y = 0; y<size.height; y++) 
    {
        //grabs an entire row of the imageData
        const uchar *src_pic_point = (uchar *)(src_pic->imageData + y*src_pic->widthStep);

        //goes through each column
        for (int x = 0; x<size.width; x++) 
        {
            //for each bin
            for (int z = 0; z < anzBin; z++)
            {
                //check both upper and lower limits
                if (src_pic_point[x] >= z*binSize && src_pic_point[x] < (z+1)*binSize)
                {
                    //increment the index that contains the point
                    histogram[z]++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return histogram;
}
```